# Is there a way to change the color of 'n' labels together with one command?

Tags: c#, vb.net, label

Is there a way to change the color of 10 labels together with one command?

For example, instead of:

```
Label1.ForeColor = Color.Black
Label2.ForeColor = Color.Black
Label3.ForeColor = Color.Black
Label4.ForeColor = Color.Black
Label5.ForeColor = Color.Black
Label6.ForeColor = Color.Black
Label7.ForeColor = Color.Black
```

I would like to use only one command to change the `ForeColor`. For example, instead of `Label1` it would be `LabelX`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just loop through all the controls of type label.
This should do the trick.

```vb
'For each control in the form
For Each ctrl As Control In Me.Controls
    'If its of type label
    If TypeOf ctrl Is Label Then
        'Change the color
        ctrl.ForeColor = Color.Black
    End If
Next
```

Edited like Vincent suggested so we don't need to declare ctr before.

As Bugs suggested here is an even shorter option:

```vb
For Each ctr In Me.Controls.OfType(Of Label)
    ctr.ForeColor = Color.Black
Next
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a recursive solution which will address `Label` controls being placed within containers such as a `GroupBox` or a `Panel`.

I will attempt to show you the difference to explain *why* a recursive method may be required. I'm using `Color.Red` to illustrate the difference. You would change the code to `Color.Black`.

The following code will set the `ForeColor` property to `Color.Red` on `Label` controls that have been placed on your form:

```vb
For Each lbl As Label In Me.Controls.OfType(Of Label)()
    lbl.ForeColor = Color.Red
Next
```

This is what it will look like:

[image]

You can see here that only `Label4` was set.

The following code will set **all** `Label` controls:

```vb
Private Sub SetAllLabelsForeColor(ByVal parent As Control)

    For Each c As Control In parent.Controls
        If TypeOf (c) Is Label Then
            c.ForeColor = Color.Red
        Else
            If c.HasChildren Then
                SetAllLabelsForeColor(c)
            End If
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

You can then call this with the following code:

```vb
SetAllLabelsForeColor(Me)
```

This is a screenshot of the outcome:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```vb
For i As Integer = 1 To 7
    Dim xL As Label = DirectCast(Controls("Label" & i.ToString), Label)
    xL.ForeColor = Color.Black
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make a loop that goes from 1 to X and get every label by name by concatenating the word `Label` with X.

```vb
Private Sub SetLabelRangeColor(ByVal [End] As Integer, ByVal Color As Color)
    SetLabelRangeColor(1, [End], Color)
End Sub

Private Sub SetLabelRangeColor(ByVal Start As Integer, ByVal [End] As Integer, ByVal Color As Color)
    If Start > [End] Then Throw New ArgumentOutOfRangeException

    For x = Start To [End]
        Dim TargetLabel As Label = TryCast(Me.Controls("Label" & x), Label)
        If TargetLabel IsNot Nothing Then
            TargetLabel.ForeColor = Color
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

**Usage:**

```vb
SetLabelRangeColor(<end label no.>, <color>)
'Or:
SetLabelRangeColor(<start label no.>, <end label no.>, <color>)
```

**Usage examples:**

```vb
'Label 1-6:
SetLabelRangeColor(6, Color.Red)

'Label 4-9:
SetLabelRangeColor(4, 9, Color.Red)
```