# Get the checked value of radio buttons in a panel within a group box

Tags: .net, vb.net

We're doing a project at school and in my program we have two radio buttons(yes/no) that's within a panel and those panels are within a groupbox. How can I get the values from the different radio buttons then? I'm just looking at getting a True/False value. It's like a simplified list of several health issues a user should be able to say if they have or haven't and this will be sent to a database.

I tried to loop through every checkbox and appending each result to a String and then returning that String, but it returns absolutely nothing. There isn't even an error message! I have a suspicion that it might have to do with the fact that I loop through both radiobuttons in the form and checking the if-statement on both, but I don't know how to do that otherwise. Every panel will contain exactly two radio-buttons and nothing more, is it possible to find them by index?

The layout is a little like this

```
+----------------+
|   Y N          |
|+-----+         |
||  o o|         |
||Panel|         |
|+-----+         |
|Groupbox        |  
+----------------+
```

Where the two o's represents the checkboxes (the Y/N represents Yes/No).

This is the [code](https://gist.github.com/wOstensen/552c42f8ed18194387cf1b6599d3c6dd) I use to loop through everything:

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient

Public Class Egenerklaring
    ' The list of booleans that is supposed to be formatted correctly and sent to the database 
    Private verdier As List(Of Boolean) = New List(Of Boolean)
    ' A counter of how many checkboxes which is not checked at all 
    Private ikkeUtfylt As Integer

    Private Function skrivUtListe()
        Dim temp As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)
        For Each a As Boolean In verdier
            temp.Add(a.ToString)
        Next
        Return String.Join(",", temp)
    End Function

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim i As Integer = 0
        For Each a As Control In Me.Controls
            If TypeOf a Is GroupBox Then
                For Each b As Control In a.Controls
                    If TypeOf b Is Panel Then
                        For Each c As Control In b.Controls
                            If TypeOf c Is CheckBox Then
                                ' If checkbox name contains ja / yes 
                                If c.Name.Contains("ja") AndAlso DirectCast(c, CheckBox).Checked Then
                                    verdier(i) = True
                                    ' If checkbox name contains nei / no 
                                ElseIf c.Name.Contains("nei") AndAlso DirectCast(c, CheckBox).Checked Then
                                    verdier(i) = False
                                Else
                                    ikkeUtfylt += 1
                                End If
                            End If
                            i += 1
                        Next
                    End If
                Next
            End If
        Next

        If ikkeUtfylt > 0 Then
            MsgBox("Fyll ut alle boksene!")
        Else
            MsgBox(Me.skrivUtListe())
        End If

    End Sub

End Class
```

I really am stuck, and would appreciate any help at all.

Comment: It's not clear exactly what you are trying to do. You start by saying you are using `RadionButton` controls but then go onto using `CheckBox` controls. From your code I can see `CheckBox` however I'm not exactly sure what the problem is. Try `verdier.Add(True)` and `verdier.False(False)`. Also it may be worth considering a recursive method like my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43319283/6375113) which you will have to adapt. This saves having to go down each container control.

Comment: Oh, sorry. Then it makes sense that it wouldn't return anything, haha. I keep mixing up CheckBox and RadioButton.

Comment: Here is some updated code: https://gist.github.com/wOstensen/552c42f8ed18194387cf1b6599d3c6dd

Comment: Can you update your question with the correct code please. It makes it easier for future readers etc.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just record "ja"/"nei" when the user clicks the RadioButton?

Comment: See https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/232017

Answer (score 0):

**RadioButton2.Checked** will return **True** wherever it is in the form if you know its name . If your'e not supposed to know it's name then simply:

```
Dim RadioChecked as boolean
For Each gb As Control In Me.Controls
    If TypeOf gb Is GroupBox Then
        For Each tb As Control In gb.Controls
            If TypeOf tb Is Panel Then
                For Each ctr As Control In tb.Controls
                    If TypeOf ctr Is RadioButton Then
                        RadioChecked = ctr.Checked
                    EndIF
                Next
            End If
        Next
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to get the values of your `RadioButtons` is to use a recursive method:

```
Private verdier As List(Of Boolean) = New List(Of Boolean)

Private Sub GetRadionButtonCheckStatus(ByVal parent As Control)

    For Each c As Control In parent.Controls
        If TypeOf (c) Is Panel Then
            For Each rb As RadioButton In c.Controls.OfType(Of RadioButton)()
                verdier.Add(rb.Checked)
            Next
        Else
            If c.HasChildren Then
                GetRadionButtonCheckStatus(c)
            End If
        End If
    Next

End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    verdier.Clear()

    GetRadionButtonCheckStatus(Me)

    'Used for debugging
    For Each value In verdier
        Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("Value: {0}", value.ToString()))
    Next

End Sub
```

The output would look something similar to this:

```
Value: True
Value: False
```

You may need to extend on this and use a `Dictionary(Of String, Boolean)` and collect the `RadioButton.Name` property so you can correctly identify the status of each `RadionButton`:

```
Private verdier As Dictionary(Of String, Boolean) = New Dictionary(Of String, Boolean)

Private Sub GetRadionButtonCheckStatus(ByVal parent As Control)

    For Each c As Control In parent.Controls
        If TypeOf (c) Is Panel Then
            For Each rb As RadioButton In c.Controls.OfType(Of RadioButton)()
                verdier.Add(rb.Name, rb.Checked)
            Next
        Else
            If c.HasChildren Then
                GetRadionButtonCheckStatus(c)
            End If
        End If
    Next

End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    verdier.Clear()

    GetRadionButtonCheckStatus(Me)

    'Used for debugging
    For Each kvp In verdier
        Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("Key: {0} Value: {1}", kvp.Key, kvp.Value))
    Next

End Sub
```

Using this code your output would look similar to this:

```
Key: RadioButton1 Value: True
Key: RadioButton2 Value: False
```

Comment: Sorry that I haven't responded in a while, have been working with the project and so on. I found a solution I thought would work.

I thought that since every panel had exactly two radio buttons, I should be able to do
`Panel.Controls(0)` for the Ja-radio and 1 for Nei.
This is my code now: https://gist.github.com/wOstensen/4111ba0d7bf31d342d30b26329e1f421

It works for checking if any is not checked, but it does not return the correct result. Here is an image showing what I chose and what the result was: http://imgur.com/a/J4s8d
Why are almost everything False?

Answer (score 0):

Use an extension method to get all the controls on a Form, no matter how nested in containers they are. Then use LINQ

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim rbs = Me.ChildControls(Of RadioButton)()
        Dim groups = rbs.GroupBy(Of String)(Function(rb) rb.Name.Replace("ja", "").Replace("nei", ""))
        If groups.Select(Function(g) g.Sum(Function(i) If(i.Checked, 1, 0))).Sum() <> groups.Count Then
            MessageBox.Show("Fyll ut alle boksene!")
        Else
            Dim result =
                groups.
                Select(
                    Function(g)
                    Return g.First().Name.Replace("ja", "").Replace("nei", "") &
                        "=" & g.Where(Function(i) i.Name.Contains("ja")).First().Checked
                End Function)
            MessageBox.Show(String.Join(", ", result))
        End If

    End Sub

End Class

Module code

    <System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()>
    Public Function ChildControls(Of T As Control)(ByVal parent As Control) As List(Of T)
        Dim result As New List(Of T)
        For Each ctrl As Control In parent.Controls
            If TypeOf ctrl Is T Then result.Add(CType(ctrl, T))
            result.AddRange(ctrl.ChildControls(Of T)())
        Next
        Return result
    End Function

End Module
```

[image]

Notice that the results contain the names of the RadioButtons without "ja" / "nei". You could alternately hold the parameter name (database column?) in the Tag property of the RadioButton and return that, or even make the RadioButton names like "jaParameter1", "neiParameter1", etc. - that's how I would do it.