# Loop through validated event Textboxes vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I was wondering how to loop through all textboxes in a form and fire validated event... i know this is has been asked before but my question is ..
if these text boxes run different code then how to fire them with one loop at form_load :

```
Private Sub _dayRev1_Validated(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles _dayRev1.Validated
    msgbox("Hello")
end sub

private sub _dayRev2_Validated(sender as object , e as eventArgs) Handles _dayRev2.Validated
    msgbox("bye")
end sub
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to change the color of 'n' labels together with one command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43317174/is-there-a-way-to-change-the-color-of-n-labels-together-with-one-command)

Comment: The point of the `Validated` event is to let you know that a control has passed validation.  If you're talking about doing something from the `Load` event handler of the form then I'm guessing that there has actually been no validation, so the `Validated` event should be irrelevant. As always, if you want perform the same action at different times then you should be putting the code for that action in its own method and then calling that method at different times, e.g. from the form's `Load` event handler and the `Validated` event handler of a `TextBox`.

Comment: That said, you can call the form's `ValidateChildren` method to force each child control to raise its `Validating` and `Validated` events.  That is normally done just before saving data, to make sure that even controls that have never received focus are validated.

Comment: thanks a lot @jmcihinney validateChildern is the solution...