# How can I Count the Number of Buttons on a Form with a specific Property?

Tags: vb.net

Say I have 5 buttons on a form. Two of them have a BackColor of Black. How can I count only those two buttons, and vice versa (counting only the three non-coloured ones)?

Comment: Simply use the solution from Bugs and instead of changing color check the color: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43317174/is-there-a-way-to-change-the-color-of-n-labels-together-with-one-command/43317730#43317730

Answer (score 0):

Try this (based on [Mederic's comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44523817/how-can-i-count-the-number-of-buttons-on-a-form-with-a-specific-property#comment76039629_44523817)):

```
Dim blackCount As Integer = 0
Dim nonBlackCount As Integer = 0

For Each control In Me.Controls.OfType(Of Button)
    If control.BackColor = Color.Black Then
        blackCount += 1
    Else
        nonBlackCount += 1
    End If
Next
```

Then the counts you are requesting for black and non-black Buttons will be stored in the `blackCount` and `nonBlackCount` variables, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer Linq and only want to count one type (not both at once), I believe this would do the trick too:

```
Dim blackCount = Me.Controls.OfType(Of Button)
                            .Where(Function(c) c.BackColor = Color.Black).Count
```

The explicit loop is better if you want to count both types, since it will only iterate the `Controls` collection once.