# VB - Change Colors on Children doesn't work

Tags: vb.net

I have created a For Each loop that goes through all controls and change it's color if it finds it. The problem is, it won't change the color of the label:

```
Sub SetColorSettings(ByVal parent As Control)

    parent.SuspendLayout()

    For Each c As Control In parent.Controls
        If TypeOf (c) Is TableLayoutPanel Then
            c.BackColor = Color.White
        ElseIf TypeOf (c) Is Label Then
            c.ForeColor = Color.Black
        Else
            If c.HasChildren Then
                SetColorSettings(c)
            End If
        End If
    Next

    parent.ResumeLayout()
    parent.Refresh()

End Sub
```

I then apply the changes with `SetColorSettings(Me)` in another sub, or Function.

**Note:** In my form, the label is directly placed within the Table Layout Panel, so technically the label should be a child to the Table Layout Panel.

I personally believe that these lines are messing with me some how:

```
If c.HasChildren Then
    SetColorSettings(c)
End If
```

Comment: Did you try to debug your code to see the flow? I guess if the control is `TableLayoutPanel` you are not calling the method for its children

Comment: @Pikoh, thanks for the quick answer, I am very new to Visual Studio, so the debugging tools are something new to me. Could you give me a hint to where I should start looking for information on this?

Comment: Well, then your first step is learning to debug in Visual Studio. It's a basic skill, see [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debugger-feature-tour)

Comment: Thanks for the documentation on Debuging, it works in a similar way to other software.

What I found was that the For Each loops goes through all the labels outside of the Table Layout Panel and changes them. In the Table Layout Panel, it never "selects / finds" the labels. So it seems like you are on the right track. I need to find a way to access the labels within the Table Layout Panel. I also noticed that it never landed on `SetColorSettings(c)`


EDIT: Original Code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43317174/is-there-a-way-to-change-the-color-of-n-labels-together-with-one-command

Comment: Try the code in my answer and tell me if it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that if the control is `TableLayoutPanel` you are not calling the method for its children. You have to call `SetColorSettings(c)` every time the control has children. Try this code:

```
Sub SetColorSettings(ByVal parent As Control)

parent.SuspendLayout()

For Each c As Control In parent.Controls
    If TypeOf (c) Is TableLayoutPanel Then
        c.BackColor = Color.White
    ElseIf TypeOf (c) Is Label Then
        c.ForeColor = Color.Black
    End If

    If c.HasChildren Then
        SetColorSettings(c)
    End If

Next

parent.ResumeLayout()
parent.Refresh()

End Sub
```